# Refresh Datepicker beforeShowDay On Dropdown Change

Tags: datepicker

I can't figure out how to update the beforeShowDay upon select change..

```
<select id="DayForReg1" name="DayForReg1">
    <option value="1">Monday</option>
    <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
    <option value="4">Thursday</option>
    <option value="5">Friday</option>
    <option value="6">Saturday</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="txtDate"/>
```

My Javascript:

```
$('#DayForReg1').change(function(){
    var day1 = $('#DayForReg1').val();
    $( "#txtDate").datepicker({beforeShowDay: function(date){var day = date.getDay();return [day == day1];}});
});
```

See my jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/t4VM5/128/ (try changing the day dropdown and clicking on the datepicker)

Thanks,

Comment: I found the answer. I think the reason why it didn't work at first because datepicker function can't read the value of day1 variable. So instead of returning day1 variable in the datepicker's return, I returned the elements.val() like this "return [day == $('#DayForReg1').val()]"

http://jsfiddle.net/t4VM5/129/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I think the reason why it didn't work at first because datepicker function can't read the value of day1 variable. So instead of returning day1 variable in the datepicker's return, I returned the elements.val() like this "return [day == $('#DayForReg1').val()]"